# C#,asp.net gridview ,edit a value using the radiobutton

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using a grid in which inside the item template(the first one in which radio button is there). i use link button instead of radiobutton ,when i click on it iam able to edit as the textbox appears, but if i use the radio button,that editing option is not coming;

aspx:

```
<div id="loginblock">
    <table>
        <tr>
  <td>UserName:</td>

            <td>
<asp:TextBox ID="username" runat="server" onBlur="txtvalidation();" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:TextBox>
      </td>
            <td>
                <div id="warning" style="color:aqua;width:100px" runat="server">

                </div>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="PlS Enter Password" ControlToValidate="pwd"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

            </td>
            </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Password:</td>
            <td>
 <asp:TextBox ID="pwd" runat="server" TextMode="Password" ></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Button ID="btnLogin" runat="server" OnClick="btnLogin_Click" Text="Button" />
    </td>
            </tr>
        <tr>
            <asp:GridView ID="grd" runat="server" OnRowEditing="selectrd_CheckedChanged"  AutoGenerateColumns="false" DataKeyNames="userid">
          <Columns>
              <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="edition">
             <ItemTemplate>
             <asp:RadioButton ID="rdnselect" runat="server"   CommndName="edit" />

             </ItemTemplate>
              </asp:TemplateField>
           <asp:BoundField HeaderText="ids" DataField="userid" />
              <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="password">
                  <ItemTemplate>
                      <%# Eval("pwd") %>
                  </ItemTemplate>
                  <EditItemTemplate>
                      <asp:TextBox ID="edits" runat="server"   Text='<%# Eval("pwd") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                  </EditItemTemplate>
              </asp:TemplateField>
          </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
```

cs:

```
protected void selectrd_CheckedChanged(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{

    grd.SelectedIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
    ldgrid();

}
```

Here if we remove the radiobutton and insert link button,onclick of the link button we can edit the values,pls say me how to do the same operation with the radio button.

Comment: Can you post your `btnLogin_Click` function?

Comment: the login_click is not related to my question,my question is only about the gridview.

Comment: yea I got the events mixed up, ignore my comment.